# bash: shortcut function which takes scp arguments

Tags: bash

I need to write a function in my .bashrc which allows me to use a shortcut key sequence for my scp command and takes the files as arguments after.

**So I want to type:** abc file

**And have it run:** scp name@server: file

*edit
Have tried:

```
function abc() { scp name@server: "$@"; }
```

and

```
abc () {
    files=''
    for x in "$@"
    do
        files="$files"
    done
    scp name@server: "$files"
}
```

**Success!**

```
abc() { scp "$@" name@server:; }
```

Comment: What have you tried and why did it fail?

Comment: Have added code. But I think I'm quite far off, and it's probably a quick thing, so not sure if this adds to value of the question.

Comment: It's just SO policy, because "Can someone write me a program that does X?" is considered off-topic.  Your first function actually does what you ask though. Have you verified that `scp name@server: file` actually does what you want? If not, obviously scripting something to run it will also not do what you want

Comment: I get "abc: command not found" error

Comment: If you added this to your `.bashrc`, run `source ~/.bashrc` first. Alternatively, paste the function definition directly into the same shell first

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes, I've sourced it. Unsure what you mean by paste into same shell first?

Comment: are you sure that's the command you want?

Comment: Solved! a restart helped, but function still did not move file. Have rewritten above, and it's working. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is **Not Recommended** to edit .bashrc file for such trifle jobs. However, if the command is really useful, add this to your :

`scpme() { scp ~/"@" username2@destination_host:~/; }`

Now you can use it from Shell like: `scpme somefile.txt`

Comment: I tried this but am still getting: -bash: scpme: command not found

Comment: Why would this not be recommended? If it works it speeds up workflow, and I can't see a downside. What am I missing?

Comment: You are supposed to make aliases / functions for long and repetitive scripts / tasks. `scp` does / should not take up that much time typing in. A cluttered .bashrc file is not recommended for your usability purposes. You're allowed to do whatever you like with yours.  

Did you run  `source ~/.bashrc`? check @thaotherguy 's comment

Comment: Yes, I've been sourcing it. Good to know, thank you. For me this is a repetitive task with a long server name, so it would be an absolute joy to have this running.

Comment: A restart helped, and got the function running. However, this function written as is still brought a "this is not a file" error. Possibly because it's pulling from main directory and not the current folder? Unsure why, but wanted to note for anyone who references this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**Success!**

abc() { scp "$@" name@server:; }